# Jekyll Pagination on every page

Tags: ruby, pagination, jekyll

As we know Jekyll default pagination just support for index.html, and I want to create blog.html include pagination there.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you create a directory called `/blog` and place an `index.html` file inside there, then you can add a setting to the `_config.yml` that says `paginate_path: "blog/page:num"`. Instead of using the default `index.html` in your root folder as the paginator template, this will use `/blog/index.html`. The paginator will generate pages like `/blog/page2/` and `/blog/page3/` as needed.

This will get you to `yourwebsite.com/blog`, but if you want to get to `yourwebsite.com/blog.html` you'll probably have to use a redirect.

Comment: Thanks @HassanAzimi :) Glad it was helpful.