# Pagination with Blog/index.html in Jekyll-3.2.1

Tags: pagination, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I am having a problem that seems to be somewhat common with using pagination on pages other than `index.html` in a Jekyll project.

I found this post that seemed to be exactly what I am looking for:

[Jekyll Pagination on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248607/jekyll-pagination-on-every-page)

However, the solution does not work for me. According to the documentation on Jekyll's website, the following code in `_config.yml` should change the paginator to use `/Blog/index.html` rather than `/index.html`:

```
gems: [jekyll-paginate]
paginate: 2
paginate_path: "/blog/page:num/"
```

I have rebuilt and restarted my local server, but the paginator still only works on the `/index.html` and not `/Blog/index.html`.

Does anyone have an idea what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paginator internal logic is to :

- (from code comment) "Determine if a page is a possible candidate to be a template page. Page's name must be `index.html` and exist in any of the directories between the site source and `paginate_path`."
- choose the one closest to `paginate_path` in length.

In your case **Blog/index.html** is not recognized as existing in **/blog/** path, because `Blog != blog`.

Or you rename your containing folder to **blog**, or you set `paginate_path: "/Blog/page:num/"`

Comment: Wow.. Thank you so much @David Jaquel. I spent about 4 hours on this issue, and can't believe it was that simple!